# Тесты Rspec на Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

В тестах я полный ноль, посоветуйте, а лучше хотя бы начало помогите с тестами, очень прошу.

tasks_controller.rb

```
class TasksController < ApplicationController
expose :task, -> {current_user.tasks.find(params[:id])}
expose :active_tasks, -> {current_user.tasks.where(active:     false).order('priority ASC')}
expose :completed_tasks, -> {current_user.tasks.where(active: true).order('priority ASC')}

def index
render json: {active: active_tasks, completed: completed_tasks}, status: 200,  each_serializer: TasksSerializer
end

def show
render json: task, status: 200, each_serializer: TaskSerializer
end

def create
task = current_user.tasks.create(task_params)
render json: task.id, status: 201, each_serializer: TaskSerializer
end

def update
if task.update(task_params)
render json: task, status: 200
else
render json: task.errors, status: 422, each_serializer: TaskSerializer
end
end

def destroy
if task.destroy
return head(:ok)
else
return head(:bad_request)
end
end

def batch_destroy
tasks = current_user.tasks.where(id: params[:ids]).destroy_all
end

private

def task_params
params.require(:task).permit(:title, :description, :priority, :due_date, :active)
end
end
```

task.rb

```
class Task < ApplicationRecord
belongs_to :user

validates :title, presence: true,
length: {
  maximum: 10
}

validates :description, presence: true,
length: {
  minimum: 4,
  maximum: 10
}
validates :priority, presence: true
end
```

Comment: Пожалуйста: https://relishapp.com/rspec/docs/gettingstarted Ничего более конкретного в текущей постановке вопроса предложить не представляется возможным.

Answer (score 2):

Доброго времени суток.

Тесты на Rspec начинаются с теории что и зачем необходимо тестировать. У меня "под рукой" всегда висят вот эти ссылки:

Про тестирование с помощью Rspec

[Model specs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-7/docs/model-specs)

[Controller specs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-7/docs/controller-specs)

[Matchers](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-7/docs/matchers)

[Request specs](https://relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-rails/v/3-7/docs/request-specs/request-spec)

Про правильное тестирование

[Better Specs](http://www.betterspecs.org/ru/)

Про сопутствующее...

[FactoryBot Getting Started](https://www.rubydoc.info/gems/factory_bot/file/GETTING_STARTED.md)

Если кратко, то тесты с помощью Rspec или любой другой библиотеки помогут тебе намного реже ходить в консоль или в браузер, чтобы убедиться, что твой код работает. Каждая составляющая проекта: модель, представление, контроллер, маилер и прочее, может быть проверена на т.н. ожидаемое поведение. Например: метод контроллера (action) должен возвращать определенный статус в ответе, изменять или не изменить количество записей в таблице, рендерить определенное представление. Каждый аспект работы твоего приложения может и в большинстве случаев должен быть протестирован, другими словами "покрыт тестами".

В практическом смысле, необходимо подготовить проект к тестированию. Для этого в Gemfile  добавляется ряд библиотек. В моем случае из проекта в проект "кочует" следующий набор:

```
group :development, :test do
  gem 'rspec-rails' # собственно сам RSpec
  gem 'factory_bot_rails' # фабрики, которые серьезно упрощают жизнь тестировщика
  gem 'database_cleaner' # штука, которая очищает тестовую БД между тестами
  gem 'rails-controller-testing' # позволяет тестировать контроллеры чуть в более широком смыслке
end
```

Необходимо установить библиотеки и инициализировать rspec

```
bundle install
rails generate rspec:install
```

Теперь в директории `/spec` можно создавать файлы с тестами проекта. Например для твоего контроллера `TasksController` примитивный тест может выглядеть так:

```
# /spec/controller/task_controller_spec.rb
require  'rails_helper'
RSpec.describe TaskController, type:  :controller  do
  # группа тестов, которая отвечает за тестирование экшена  index
  describe "GET #index" do
    # тест проверяет что возвращается корретный запрос
    it "returns a success response" do
      get :index
      expect(response).to have_http_status(:ok)
    end

    # ниже должны быть тесты которые проверяют на рендеринг определенных
    # представлений и создание (assigns) определенных экземпляров
    it "renders index template"  do
    end
    it "assigns tasks" do
    end
  end
end
```

Вообще это очень обширная тема чтобы уложиться  в короткий пост. Благо информации в сети достаточно.

Для образца можешь посмотреть на мой небольшой проект, в котором имеются некоторое количество тестов для моделей, контроллеров и представлений:

https://github.com/nmix/ams